# SystemRescueCd: Save files from crashed Windows 7, cannot discover the harddrive

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mount, ntfs, rescue-disk

My laptop suddendly quit working, simply boots no longer, giving an error stating that it cannot find a disk where to boot from. I suspect that the harddrive is corrupted or broken.

Well, I booted the computer with my SystemRescueCd USB installation in order to take a looksy. I cannot get any sight of the harddrive, below are the commands I've executed and their output

`fsarchiver probe simple`

```
[======DISK======] [=============NAME==============] [====SIZE====] [MAJ] [MIN]
[sda             ] [DataTraveler 2.0               ] [   489.00 MB] [  8] [  0]

[=====DEVICE=====] [==FILESYS==] [======LABEL======] [====SIZE====] [MAJ] [MIN] 
[loop0           ] [squashfs   ] [<unknown>        ] [   259.99 MB] [  7] [  0] 
[sda1            ] [vfat       ] [SYSLINUX         ] [   488.23 MB] [  8] [  1]
```

Here the DataTraveler 2.0 is my bootable USB stick with the SystemRescueCd on it.

`fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 512 MB, 512753664 bytes
56 heads, 32 sectors/track, 558 cylinders, total 1001472 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0365986f

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          32      999935      499952    b  W95 FAT32
```

I also skimmed through dmesg and tried to grep it for **"hda"**, but found no indication of the hardrive.

`lshw` gives me some output for **SATA controller** and such, but can't really say what to look for in here.

**Is this a lost cause and the hardrive is simply busted? Or is there something else I can do to discover the drive for mounting it and saving the data?**

**UPDATE**

Another boot with SystemRescueCd and `fdisk -l` now shows the drive as

```
Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x3421b7ec

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    27265023    13631488   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2   *    27265024    27469823      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        27469824   488394751   230462464    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

and `fsarchiver probe simple`

```
[======DISK======] [=============NAME==============] [====SIZE====] [MAJ] [MIN]
[sda             ] [Hitachi HTS54502               ] [   232.89 GB] [  8] [  0]
```

**Note: The USB drive mentioned above is now mapped as /dev/sdb**

Attempts to mount the device give me the following output

```
root@sysresccd /root % mount -r /dev/sda1 /mnt/windows 
mount: special device /dev/sda1 does not exist
```

Same error also for sda2 and sda3 when attempted to mount.

Also `lshw` now shows the device details.

**Update 2**

One more thing I just realised. This time I booted SystemRescueCd so that it's fully loaded to memory. Maybe this has something to do with how the other drive is shown.

Comment: Does the drive show in the BIOS/UEFI?

Comment: @ernie, Yes, the boot order page shows `IDE0 : Hitachi ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was too close to see. After boot, SystemRescueCd prints out basic usage on the terminal. There, it says to use [ntfs-3g](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfs-3g) to mount Windows NTFS drives for full read/write support. So, simply using the following command, I managed to mount the drive on broken laptop

```
ntfs-3g /dev/sda3 /mnt/windows
```

P.S. If one wishes to bee extra careful and avoid making any mess on the drive, it can be mounted read-only `ro` option. The documentation actually says that this should be used when Windows is hibernated.